# Reading jSON object request via key-value pair

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I am trying to read `jSON` response in form of key value pair.

When I am **manually hitting the URL via browser** I am getting the required status code/response via `jSON` object

`{"status":"0","responseCode":"1021","response":{"message":"Please check your Settings ","data":"2012-11-24, 7:28 am"}}`

The same expected response is not obtained when I am trying to do it via my app.My code when I am sending data via app

```
[dictionnary setObject:@"admin"  forKey:@"username"];
[dictionnary setObject:@"123123" forKey:@"password"];

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];

NSString *urlString = @"MY CALL URL";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSLog(@"response is obtained");

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

Response I am getting via code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>PHP notice</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent;margin:0;padding:0;}
    body{line-height:1;}
    ol,ul{list-style:none;}
    blockquote,q{quotes:none;}
    blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none;}
    :focus{outline:0;}
    ins{text-decoration:none;}
    del{text-decoration:line-through;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}

    body {
        font: normal 9pt "Verdana";
        color: #000;
        background: #fff;
    }

    h1 {
        font: normal 18pt "Verdana";
        color: #f00;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }

    h2 {
        font: normal 14pt "Verdana";
        color: #800000;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }

    h3 {
        font: bold 11pt "Verdana";
    }

    pre {
        font: normal 11pt Menlo, Consolas, "Lucida Console", Monospace;
    }

    pre span.error {
        display: block;
        background: #fce3e3;
    }

    pre span.ln {
        color: #999;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    pre span.error-ln {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 1em 4em;
    }

    .version {
        color: gray;
        font-size: 8pt;
        border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
        padding-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .message {
        color: #000;
        padding: 1em;
        font-size: 11pt;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        line-height: 160%;
    }

    .source {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .code pre {
        background-color: #ffe;
        margin: 0.5em 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
        line-height: 125%;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
    }

    .source .file {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .traces {
        margin: 2em 0;
    }

    .trace {
        margin: 0.5em 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

    .trace.app {
        border: 1px dashed #c00;
    }

    .trace .number {
        text-align: right;
        width: 2em;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

    .trace .content {
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

    .trace .plus,
    .trace .minus {
        display:inline;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #000;
        color:#000;
        font-size:10px;
        line-height:10px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0 1px;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
    }

    .trace.collapsed .minus,
    .trace.expanded .plus,
    .trace.collapsed pre {
        display: none;
    }

    .trace-file {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0.2em;
    }

    .trace-file:hover {
        background: #f0ffff;
    }
    /*]]>*/
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>PHP notice</h1>

        <p class="message">
            Undefined index: signature  </p>

        <div class="source">
            <p class="file">/var/www/protected/controllers/Authenticate.php(955)</p>
            <div class="code"><pre><span class="ln">943</span>   

            <td class="number">
                #7          </td>
            <td class="content">
                <div class="trace-file">
                                            <div class="plus">+</div>
                        <div class="minus">–</div>
                                        &nbsp;/var/yii-1.1.10.r3566/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): <strong>CWebApplication</strong>-><strong>processRequest</strong>()               </div>

                <div class="code"><pre><span class="ln">157</span>      */
<span class="ln">158</span>     public function run()
<span class="ln">159</span>     {
<span class="ln">160</span>         if($this-&gt;hasEventHandler(&#039;onBeginRequest&#039;))
<span class="ln">161</span>             $this-&gt;onBeginRequest(new CEvent($this));
<span class="error"><span class="ln error-ln">162</span>         $this-&gt;processRequest();
</span><span class="ln">163</span>         if($this-&gt;hasEventHandler(&#039;onEndRequest&#039;))
<span class="ln">164</span>             $this-&gt;onEndRequest(new CEvent($this));
<span class="ln">165</span>     }
<span class="ln">166</span> 
<span class="ln">167</span>     /**
</pre></div>            </td>
        </tr>
                        <tr class="trace app expanded">
            <td class="number">
                #8          </td>
            <td class="content">
                <div class="trace-file">
                                            <div class="plus">+</div>
                        <div class="minus">–</div>
                                        &nbsp;/var/www/index.php(13): <strong>CApplication</strong>-><strong>run</strong>()             </div>

                <div class="code"><pre><span class="ln">08</span> defined(&#039;YII_DEBUG&#039;) or define(&#039;YII_DEBUG&#039;,true);
<span class="ln">09</span> // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
<span class="ln">10</span> defined(&#039;YII_TRACE_LEVEL&#039;) or define(&#039;YII_TRACE_LEVEL&#039;,3);
<span class="ln">11</span> 
<span class="ln">12</span> require_once($yii);
<span class="error"><span class="ln error-ln">13</span> Yii::createWebApplication($config)-&gt;run();
</span></pre></div>         </td>
        </tr>
                </table>
    </div>

    <div class="version">
        2012-11-24 07:38:18 Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/">Yii Framework</a>/1.1.10  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var traceReg = new RegExp("(^|\\s)trace-file(\\s|$)");
var collapsedReg = new RegExp("(^|\\s)collapsed(\\s|$)");

var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var j=0,len=e.length;j<len;j++){
    if(traceReg.test(e[j].className)){
        e[j].onclick = function(){
            var trace = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if(collapsedReg.test(trace.className))
                trace.className = trace.className.replace("collapsed", "expanded");
            else
                trace.className = trace.className.replace("expanded", "collapsed");
        }
    }
}
/*]]>*/
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems there is error with the webservice PHP script as it shows : **Undefined index: signature**

Comment: is this your url NSString *urlString = @"MY CALL URL";???

Comment: @Rajneesh071,Siba Prasad When I am hitting it via browser it is working. Not working via app.

Comment: it may be GET Request can you try:   /index.php/api/transaction/model/transactionsuccess?username=admin&password=12123

Comment: `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/index.php/api/transaction/model/transactionsuccess?username=admin&password=1212‌​3"]];`

// Perform request and get JSON as a NSData object

'NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];`

    `NSLog(@"response=%@",response );` and use this code.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota The response is already mentioned in the question

Comment: you used the request like this : NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/index.php/api/transaction/model/transactionsuccess?username=adm‌​in&password=1212‌​3"]];

Comment: See the last portion of my edited code.

Comment: request Error Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)"

Answer (score 0):

specify in your URLRequest that you dont want html but you want raw json

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

to:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];//!!!
```

Comment: seems good.. though when you ask: you dont want to do synchronous requests :) look into [NSURLConnection sendAsyncRequest:withCompletionHandler:]

Comment: Hey mate I am totally messed up with this issue. Can you kindly make efforts to post the exact working code,please

Comment: The response I am getting is null :(

Comment: THEN mohit is right, seems to be a server issue or a wrong url

Answer (score 0):

You can try  the following code May be help you.

```
NSString *username = emailField.text;
        NSString *password = passwordField.text;
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictionnary setObject:@"admin"  forKey:@"username"];
        [dictionnary setObject:@"123456" forKey:@"password"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                             error:&error];   

        NSString *urlString = @"Sample URL";

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
        NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
        NSError *requestError = NULL;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
         NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

if it is a GET Request then, can you try link : **/index.php/api/transaction/model/transactionsuccess?username=admin&password=1212‌​3**

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/index.php/api/transaction/model/transactionsuccess?username=adm‌​in&password=1212‌​3"]];

 // Perform request and get JSON as a NSData object


NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSLog(@"response=%@",response );
```

and use this code.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is related to server side; so you must consult to back-end developer of the service and more possibly, check at service side the data hit using POST or GET, and if back-end is of php, so for a moment advised him to use $request instead of $get or $post, just to test. Also, this fact is obvious as you mentioned that as you tried the url from browser you get the required json, but in the case of POST you never able to do that.

I'm 100% sure this is from server side.If possible provide me the required server url with test auth variables.
(cross-check your full url with the params as you provide either via break points or via log.)

Comment: under 1 endpoint, server can provide multiple answers based on HTTP Method and REQUEST HEADERS :) to me it seems reasonable to set those headers correctly on the client side

Comment: Hey Djan, nice to see you.That's only possible if at server side the case is handle by $request otherwise you never get the data with wrong HTTPMethod.

Comment: And, for the above url which is in POST, he's not able to get the same url due to POST and, that's why I wrote he never get the data from browser, he can only if he manually write the url not of as logged by xcode in this case :)

Comment: yes, yours is a possibility for sure - Im not denying that :) but it isnt 100% a server error. if my idea doesnt solve the problem I'd say you are very correct

Comment: sorry I dont get that. he used 'READ_URL' as a placeholder.. so why cant it be the same in browser and App?

Comment: That scenario I've already faced and I also tried the same solution as provided by you but at that time I forget about authentication at server side, if it can accept all request than what is the need of using extra param :)

Comment: Just add, as you tried to specify that it only accepts json type data, but one more interesting thing is that at server none of HTML data was to be sent,then food for thought is that from where this html arrive :)

Comment: Djan, just check his response coming to be null as what I referred.That's really a server side scenario. Now request him to take the response code so he can understand and possibly he get either 4xx or 5xx err

Comment: Onkar,use this and if needed full code for taking response status ,give me a shout or you can google:    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

Comment: Do this in delegate of HTTP(any concern get back to me)-- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  NSLog(@"Received response: %@", response);
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"\n\n\nThe response status is->%d\n\n\n",responseStatusCode);
}

Comment: And, if possible you do send me whatever print by responseStatusCode, so we can assure that it's server side stuff and you can enjoy a cup of tea :)